# how to swap two character of a character array? in c

Tags: c, char, swap

How can you replace two characters in a character array? For example:

charecter array : `peter`

Replace the two characters `p` and `t` and give the following output:

`teper`

its my try(it is wrong):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap(char*,char*);

main() {
    int n,i,j;
    char str[30][30];
    printf("how many names?:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("name %d?",i+1);
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    char ch1,ch2;
    printf(" which letters of name %d?:",i+1);
    scanf("%c%c",&ch1,&ch2);
    swap(&ch1,&ch2);
    printf("\n %s",str[i]);
    }
}
void swap(char *a,char *b){
 char temp;
 temp=*a;
 *a=*b;
 *b=temp;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've attempted.

Comment: Please use only one of the tags, C or C++ - the solutions could be very different for the two *different* languages.

Comment: There's a standard function template for swapping. Its called `std::swap`

Comment: @TedLyngmo That won't work in C. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat That was the point :-) oh, but now c++ was removed so comment deleted.

Comment: Please note std::swap is a solution for C++, not C

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED
 i edited it and add my attempt.

Comment: @AdrianMole  i edited it,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```c
// you can use the same logic in c++
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char * a, char * b) {
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "peter";
    
    printf("before -> %s\n", str);
    swap(&str[0], &str[2]); // swap p and t
    printf("After -> %s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah mb, edited :D thanks

Comment: `char str[] = "peter";` or `char str[] = { 'p', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r', '\0' };` without forgetting the NULL byte ;)

Comment: @Scouarn. ay, thanks edited it

Comment: @Tedlyngmo  The user must enter two characters in the program.

Comment: @moh-co this is the only the logic tho, the op should be able to write their own solution using this

Comment: @moh-co Perhaps you should take a look at [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find the characters that the user enters.